# Using Document.write() with an object to create <p> in HTML

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use `document.write()` method in JavaScript to write a sentence with `<p>` tags using an object, `you`. I have tried to concatenate a sentence like the example below, but it prints the object on a different line.

I need it to form a proper sentence with everything on the same line and be able to create a paragraph with multiple sentences.

#### Attempt

```
var you = {
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  age: '32'
};

document.write("<p>Hello my name is "</p> + firstName + " " + lastName)
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem

Comment: `but it prints the object on a different line.` It shouldn't, it should result in a `SyntaxError` due to `"<p>Hello my name is "</p>`

Comment: opinion: `document.write` is almost never the right way to add "dynamic" content to a web page ... and by almost I mean 100%

Answer (score 0):

`<p>` element is block element it automatically creates a like break. You should use `<span>`. And also access `firstName` and `lastName` from the `you` object otherwise they will throw error

```js
var you = {
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  age: '32'
};

document.write("<span>Hello my name is </span>" + you.firstName + " " + you.lastName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements, you can use [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Note that IE is not supported without a compiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)

```js
var you = {
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  age: '32'
};

document.write(`<p>Hello my name is ${you.firstName} ${you.lastName}</p>`);
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you seem to have a typo which I assume is causing some issues.

```
document.write("<p>Hello my name is "</p> + firstName + " " + lastName);
```

In the line above you have the `"` on the wrong side of the `</p>`, so the `</p>` is outside of the string and will cause issues when parsed. Plus you should refer to the variables as `you.VARIABLE_NAME` like `you.lastName`.

Also, if you're looking to put the whole line inside the same paragraph, then just move the closing paragraph to the end when you build the string. Like this:

```
document.write("<p>Hello my name is " + you.firstName + " " + you.lastName + "</p>");
```

If you want to write multiple lines within the same paragraph you can either just have everything in the same line of code like this:

```
document.write("<p>Hello my name is " + you.firstName + " " + you.lastName + " and I'm " + you.age + " years old." + "</p>");
```

Or you can separate it on a few different lines of code to make it easier to read and follow, like this:

```
document.write("<p>");
document.write("Hello my name is " + you.firstName + " " + you.lastName);
document.write("and I am " + you.age + " years old.")
document.write("</p>")
```

**EDIT:**
You might also want to try template strings. If you use `` ` `` for your strings instead of `'` or `"` you can refer to variables inside the string by wrapping them in `${}` like this:

```
document.write(`Hello my name is ${you.firstName} ${you.lastName} and I'm ${you.age} years old.`)
```

Just a thought! You can read more about template strings here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Also, there are better ways then `document.write` to add text to a page. Here's a simple guide that might be useful:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_output.asp

Answer (score 0):

You're closing your `<p>` and have invalid quotation groupings. You can use template literals like so:

```js
var you = {
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  age: '32'
};

document.write(`<p>Hello my name is ${you.firstName} ${you.lastName}</p>`);
```

ES5 syntax:

```js
var you = {
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  age: '32'
};

document.write("<p>Hello my name is " + you.firstName + " " + you.lastName + "</p>");
```